# Bash Non-Sense - Variable Not Passing Correctly

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu, tar

When I echo out the file and when I put the name in the command directly, it works fine, but when I run it with the file name as a variable. It gives me a BAD vs a GOOD. this is obviously a shorter equation to the longer one I am trying ot get to work, but I feel if I can get this to work, then I am good.

Anyone? Any Ideas why it gives me a BAD for this?

```
if [ -f /home/publish/swift/$TAR_FILE ]; then echo "good"; else echo "bad"; fi
```

But a GOOD when I use:

```
if [ -f /home/publish/swift/swift_tar_1212.tgz ]; then echo "good"; else echo "bad"; fi
```

Comment: Can you post the line where you set `TAR_FILE`?

Comment: This isn't enough information to reproduce the bug -- you'd have to show where and how `TAR_FILE` is supposed to be set.

Comment: ...after all, how can we possibly help debug a problem **PASSING** a variable when you only show us how you're **USING** the variable after it's already been passed?

Comment: If you do not know the semantics, your only chance is to guess.

Comment: @lx42.de, ...and guessing is what we're doing. If the content of `TAR_FILE` were `swift_tar_1212.tgz` and `IFS` were at its default value, this issue couldn't happen -- but there's no way of knowing which of those constraints is broken, **even for someone who does know the semantics**.

Comment: ...after all, the question wasn't "how can I prevent this from happening?" (duh, obvs., add quotes), but "why is this happening?", and answering the directly-asked _why_ as opposed to the unasked best-practices prevention question requires more information than is given.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Maybe you misunderstood me. You are absolutely right, it was impossible to solve this question without a dialog. But why is it bad to ask such questions? Shell scripting is confusing and so was the question. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem eluded me for a few days and I knew something was weird with the string return form the other server. I have added the code that ended up working for me.

GOAL:
ssh into other server, run a command in a certain directory to determine the most recent updated .tgz, then take the name of that file and pass it into a variable so that it could be run from the current instance to SCP over. Code is below

```
#SSH into the master prod machine and find the latest TAR.
TARFILE="$(ssh -i cross-key -t login@server  'bash -c "cd /home/publish/swift; find *.tgz -type f | xargs ls -t"')"

#Telling us the latest .tgz of Swift Website
echo "TAR List:$TARFILE"

#Pass the List into an Array and then Get the first one which is the latest .tgz file
IFS=' ' read -a array <<< "$TARFILE"
TAR_FILE "${array[0]}"
```

This finally gave me the string that I needed to continue with my if and else statement.

```
if [ -f /home/publish/swift/$TAR_FILE ]; then echo "good"; else echo "bad"; fi
```

And I was able to get good - therefore I could continue with the execution of the new tgz file. I had to pass the full list into an array vs just taking the last value with:

```
$(find *.tgz -type f | xargs ls | tail -n 1)
```

What a freakin nightmare. But now it works!
I just hope this can help someone else that beats their head against the wall about this problem.

Answer (score 3):

If you set the TAR_FILE to the same value, then it should work

```
TAR_FILE='swift_tar_1212.tgz'
```

And please do yourself a favor and ALWAYS put the string into quotes:

```
if [ -f "/home/publish/swift/$TAR_FILE" ]; then echo "good"; else echo "bad"; fi
```

Single quotes, if you do not want an $... expansion.

Maybe you will find it useful to set xtrace:

```
set -x
```

turning it off with

```
set +x
```

If you want to glob for all files in a dir, without knowing their name:

```
for file in /home/publish/swift/*; do
    test -f "$file" && echo "$file"
done
```

**All** files is not perfectly correct, the hidden files are not matched this way!

```
for file in /home/publish/swift/{.*,*}; do
    test -f "$file" && echo "$file"
done
```

As @mklement0 noted, you may use shopt to modify the globbing => http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Shopt-Builtin.html
In your case the following options may help you:

```
dotglob
extglob
failglob
globstar
nocaseglob
nocasematch (``[[ ]]`` only)
nullglob (very useful)
```

It can be confusing to set these values in your .bashrc, because a lot of examples in the web are based upon the default values. Unfortunately shopt cannot be restricted to a shell function - thats pain.

Comment: Well the TAR_FILE value is not always swift_tar_1212.tgz. The example is that it does show good if I put the name of the current file, but the swift file updates a few times a day.

Comment: So you do not know the filename? Then you have to use a globbing mechanism. Please tell me exactly, what you want to do.

Comment: I added a globbing example.

Comment: Good stuff; two things worth adding: If you use bash's `[[ ... ]]` rather than the POSIX-compliant `[ ... ]` for testing, you generally do NOT need to quote the pathname (though it won't hurt); unless you need POSIX compliance, use of `[[ … ]]` is advisable, because it offers more features and fewer surprises. If you want globbing to also match hidden files, run `shopt -s dotglob` first.

Comment: Unfortunately, the `[[ ... ]]` (Execute conditional command.) are not the _better_ `[ ... ]` (Evaluate conditional expression.) braces. They do have another semantics. In most cases, you will miss programming errors covered by this.

Comment: For an in-depth discussion of `[ ... ]` vs. `[[ ... ]]`, see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/031. You'll see that you'll miss out on several useful features by sticking with `[ ... ]`, notably pattern matching and regex matching. As for terminology: `[` and its alias `test` are shell _builtins_, whose arguments are therefore parsed with _command_ semantics, whereas `[[` is a _shell keyword_ that introduces a _special parsing context_ - hence the relaxed quoting requirements and the ability to use `&&` and `||` and `(` and `)` (without escaping) inside that context.

Comment: Thank you for mentioning that page, yes there are differences. So a programmer should always carefully decide if he uses `[[` or `[` or `test`. In my opinion the `[` and quoting has priority. It is not against you.

Comment: No worries - I didn't take it personally, and I hope my previous comment didn't sound as if I did - the intent was to inform (incidentally, if you want me to be notified of your responses, you must @-mention me (@mklement0). Perhaps we're needlessly conflating two things here: if your concern is the _consistency of quoting_ (and I do see your point there), you can quote _and_ use  `[[ ... ]]`, which will allow use of the added features. By advocating use of `[ ... ]` you're willingly forgoing bash language features - which is obviously a choice you _can_ make, but it should be made _clear_.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65356/discussion-between-lx42-de-and-mklement0).

Comment: It seems that the problem I had was that the return I received from the server that was the variable of $TAR_FILE was not just in a string, it seems to have hidden characters or something. I had to push that return into an array and then do an array[0] to get the string alone.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
if [ -f "/home/publish/swift/$TAR_FILE" ]
then 
    echo "good"
else 
    echo "bad"
fi
```

Comment: Why are you editing to add the `Linux` tag. This post is applicable to many OS's, not just LInux. Avoid adding unnecessary tags the original question does not imply. I note you have done that on multiple questions tonight.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin i think it's not bad to specify at least one, what do you think? I can remove it if you don't agree

Comment: It's not worth removing, but it was just strange since it would apply equally to MAC, BSD, Linux, Unix, etc... Many times there are OS specific twists to answers, but when are aren't it is better to leave it without a OS limiting tag.